# Problems in retrieving data from database .Relative import error in views.py

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

***My model.py,views.py forms.py,html template is complete but i am not able to retreive data from database***

I tried to run my views python file but it couldn't run it and is showing relative import error .Is there error in my code or some other problem.Please Shed some light as I wasted my whole day on this with 0 result
I am getting error in my views.py that
File "views.py", line 5, in 
from .forms import Registration1
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
views.py
from django.shortcuts import render

```
#from django.http import RequestContext
#from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from .forms import Registration1
from .models import Category


#print('__file__={0:<35} | __name__={1:<20} | __package__={2: 
#<20}'.format(__file__,__name__,str(__package__)))
#count = 5

# Create your views here.

def home(request):      
  
       
#print(context_dict.values())
  
if request.method == 'POST':
stud1 = ' '
cm =Registration1(request.POST)
if cm.is_valid():
      cm1 = cm.cleaned_data['category']
      
      sm1  = cm.cleaned_data['subcateg']

      pm1 = cm.cleaned_data['product']

      reg2 = Category(category = cm1,subcateg = sm1,product = pm1)
      reg2.save()
      cm = Registration1()
    
else :

 cm = Registration1()
 stud1 = Category.objects.all()
 print(stud1)

return render(request,'registration.html', {'forms': cm ,'Register' : 
stud1} 
)
```

Models.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models

class Category(models.Model):
category = models.CharField(max_length=50,null =True)
subcateg = models.CharField(max_length=50,null = True)
product = models.CharField(max_length=50,null = True)
```

Forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Category

class Registration1(forms.ModelForm) :
class Meta :
    model = Category
    fields = ['product','subcateg','category']   
    widgets  = {
        'product' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
        'subcateg' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
        'category' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'})
         ,
    }
```

Registration.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <title>Document</title>
   <link rel = "stylesheet" href ="{% static  'project/css/bootstrap.css ' 
%}">
</head>
<body>
 <div class =  "container mt-5">
   
    <div class = "row">   

      
        <div class = "col-sm-0"> 
           <h4 class = "text-centre alert alert-info ">Add Product </h4>
        
             <form action = '' method = "POST"> 
                 {% csrf_token %}
  
   
                   {{forms.as_p}}
   
   
                     <br>
                     <input type = "submit" class = "btn btn-success" 
                      value="add">
             </form>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
           <h4 class = "text-centre alert alert-info">DataBase Table</h4>
                  
             {% if Register %}
                         
              <table class="table table-striped table-dark">
                <thead>
                 <tr>
                   <th scope="col">ID</th>
                   <th scope="col">PRODUCT</th>
                   <th scope="col">SUBCATEGORY</th>
                   <th scope="col">CATEGORY</th>
                 </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  {% for st in Register %}
                        
                               <tr>
                                  <th scope ="row">{{st.id}}</th>
                                  <td>{{st.product}}</td>
                                  <td>{{st.subcateg}}</td>
                                  <td>{{st.category}}</td>
                               </tr>
                  {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
              </table>
             {% endif %}
                

            </div>
        </div> 
    
      </div>

  <script src = "{% static 'project/css/jQuery.js' %}"></script>
  <script src = "{% static 'project/css/popper.js'%}"></script>
  <script src = "{% static 'project/css/bootstrap.js' %}"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you should post your code and ask specific questions and not asking people for the whole project

Comment: i have pasted my code here ,please check @EkremÜçüncü

Answer (score 0):

So I guess you need to declare a foreign key like [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/).
It should be something like this

```
class ProductMan(models.Model):
    subcategory= models.ForeignKey(WebSubCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class WebSubCategory(models.Model):
    category= models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I don't know if there is a mistake in the templates as you didn't post them

Comment: thank you i will post template also and will let you know if any issue will arise.

Comment: Iam getting relative import error ,and i couldn't find the solution

Comment: post your code but please seperate the codes so not all are together.

Comment: I updated ,i separated them I am quite new here so ,Iam learning how to post questions here . Sorry for such silly mistakes

Comment: from django.shortcuts import render
I guess you should add this to the top of your views

Comment: i added that but still same issue

Comment: Following is the error message   :                                                                  
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "views.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .forms import Registration1
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Comment: it cannot import your form

Comment: it may be that you have another name for your forms.py. Check the name if the error is still there change the name of your form maybe the '1' at the end is causing it.

Comment: I removed 1 from everywhere ,the problem still persists

Comment: can you post the whole error message in the question by editing the question